# How do I handle a sqlite3 no data returned on node.js

Tags: node.js, sqlite

I have a huge Sqlite3 database approximately 18.3 GB in size. I am querying it using Node.js, express.js and sqlite3. If I enter an email address stored in the database, it displays the relevant other details correctly. However if the email address is not in the database, it waits indefinitely for a response until it times out. I have tried this on my localhost and on my web hosting.

My question: Is there a way of stopping it or handling the error?

I have tried adding an if statement on rows to find out if there is a message contained with err aka err.message but the result is undefined.

```
app.get('/api/users/:email', function(request, response) {
const email = request.params['email'];

db.all("SELECT * FROM ents WHERE email = '" + email + "'", function(err, rows){
    if(rows) {
        response.send(rows);
    }
    else {
        response.send('No Data');
    }
});

});
```

On both the local machine (localhost) and web hosting, it waits for a response until it times out. The output should be a response of json containing the various fields associated with the email address or a 'no' response.

Comment: Do you have an index on `ents(email)`?

Comment: Also use parameters and not string concatenation. This is an clear SQL injection attack point.

Comment: No there is no index on `ents(email)` I'm unsure what you mean by using parameters and not string concatenation - explain please.

Comment: Also I do not understand why my node app is timing out. It shouldn't be doing that or is it because the sqlite database is so big? I wouldn't know how to add an index to the database when it has already been copied to the web hosting server.

Comment: I have just tried another couple of things but still I'm getting it hanging on both my local machine and the web hosting server where it was working before.